# Getting every 7th element from array while echoing a table

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I'm getting the data I need from `fgetcsv` and store them into `$data`. It contains a table with a header row and lot's of info. Every 7th column is the path to where the file is stored.

I've already searched for what my problem is but I can't seem the find the solution.

My Code yet:

```
echo '<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" class="csvTable" width="auto">';
$handle = fopen("index.csv", "r");
$start = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    echo '<tr>' . "\n";
    for ( $x = 0; $x < count($data); $x++) {
        if ($start == 0 && $hasTitle == true)
            echo '<th>'.$data[$x].'</th>' . "\n";
        else
            echo '<td>'.$data[$x].'</td>' . "\n";
    }
    $start++;
    echo '</tr>' . "\n";
}
fclose($handle);
echo '</table>';
```

I want to add a hyperlink via `<a href=?>` on every 7th column but I don't know how. How can I do it and is that the right way?

Comment: I would not rely on the column number. Just check if the data contains a url using for example `filter_var()` and if it does, convert it into an html link. See the examples in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: Does `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` also contains \\path\ paths?

Comment: That would depend on the `FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check every column is a 7th column or divisible by 7 you can just check if the variable is divided by 7 like this.

```
echo '<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" class="csvTable" width="auto">';
$handle = fopen("index.csv", "r");
$start = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    echo '<tr>' . "\n";
    for ( $x = 0; $x < count($data); $x++) {
        if ($start == 0 && $hasTitle == true)
            echo '<th>'.$data[$x].'</th>' . "\n";
        else
            echo '<td>'.$data[$x].'</td>' . "\n";
        if( $x && !($x % 7) ){
        echo '<a href=?>'
        }
    }

    $start++;
    echo '</tr>' . "\n";
}
fclose($handle);
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Works just fine. Except for one thing: The first collums also have the hyperlink. The first and the 7th. How can I fix that?

Comment: Works as it should be working. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the [remainder](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) by 7 of your counter is 0. If it is, then it is a multiple of seven and you can echo your desired string.

```
if($start % 7 === 0){
  echo '<a href=?>'
}
```

Comment: Would the echo look like this then?: `echo '<td><a href='.$data[$x].'>'.$data[$x].</td>' . "\n";`

Comment: Well, it works. Kinda. I missunderstood my own code. Now every 7th whole row has a hyperlink. instead, every 7th collum from each row should have the hyperlink. Got an idea?